# Angular2 @Viewchild unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testbed

I have a component like this:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;
}
```

which is using the `childComponent` to make a call, let's say like this:

```
this.childComponent.method();
```

within `ParentComponent` method.

So, when I am trying to test the `ParentComponent` method which is internally using the `ChildComponent`, the childComponent is returning as undefined.

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Declare fixture for child component inside describe.

```
let childFixture: ComponentFixture<childComponent>;
```

And now create component instance using

```
let childComp = childFixture.componentInstance;
```

Answer (score -2):

In most cases when you want to use ViewChild in your test, just add it to the your test decleration like this :

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed
            .configureTestingModule({
                imports: [],
                declarations: [ChildComponent],
                providers: [],
            })
            .compileComponents()
```

Comment: Still undefined for me.